# remove " ' " from given string

Tags: php

I want string that does not contain "'".

If my strin is **vaibhav's friend** then i want **vaibhavs friend**

Notice **vaibhav's friend** = **vaibhavs friend**

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 3):

```
$string = str_replace("'", '', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace the quotes with an empty string:

```
$string = str_replace("'","",$string);
```